# Windows Application in future to be controlled over browser

Tags: c#

I am writing a Windows application using C#. I am planning on later to allow it to be controlled over the intranet using browser also. So in future we should be able to control it both using the local interface or over the intranet from the browser.

Is there any pre-defined architecture which will allow me to do this? What are the methods of achieving this? I am new to C#/.Net.

EDIT:

The windows application needs to access the communication ports extensively, and needs to be pretty stable and would probably run for some days together.

Thanks...

Comment: how would you use the communication ports of a local PC via the browser? if it aint for the local machine, then a client server app would be best, maybe possible in silverlight too.

Comment: I was thinking I would control the Windows App from the browser based app.So that the users can access the Windows based app running on a machine from any other machine in the intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you if a specific package exists that would ease the development.  But, if I were to attempt it, after Googling and not finding something already available and meeting my needs, I would likely make my application a WCF host.  Create service entry points to accept control messages remotely.  You would also need some well-know location where to register your application so the remote system could find it.  You should be sure to provide the user with a way of disabling the application remote control feature.

Your host interface will need to run on its own thread to remain performant.  Since you are new to C#, and presumably windows forms application development, you will need to read up on how to properly talk to the GUI controls from a non-GUI thread.

Alternatively, you may want to implement your application as two distinct units, one with a GUI that does all the user interaction.  It would form service requests to send to the host portion (with no GUI).  Your app could then operate locally or be controlled remotely.

Comment: I kind of like the second approach. Having a host portion which receives and sends messages which can be used by wither the GUI or the Web App. How is the message passing between applications usually done?

Comment: WCF is common. Remoting is possible, but has mostly been replaced by WCF. WCF is bidirectional so the GUI can both send commands and receive events.  Check out the .NET 4.0 WCF which has made setting up the "service host" a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have used in a similar situation has three parts :-

1) `Win32 (local) Service`

Manages the COM ports and does whatever is necessary with the attached hardware

2) `WinForms/Console Application`

Runs on the local machine and communicates with the local service via named pipes or TCP.

3) `Web Server + Web App`

Runs on local or remote machine & communicates with local service.

The local user can shut the WinForms application down and log-off without affecting the service or remote users.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of Silverlight (the version that ships with Visual Studio 2010) allows what Microsoft terms the "Out Of Browser Experience" (OOB for short).
This allows the user to set up the Silverlight application as a desktop application as well as running through a browser.

[Rudi Grobbler has just blogged](http://www.rudigrobler.net/Blog/s-oob-w7) about how he went about setting this up on his PC.

Comment: But my windows based application needs to access communication ports and stuff which i think is not possible using Silverlight OOB. Is that right? I have added this as an edit..

Comment: Hmm, that's going to be a problem.  To be honest, the only way I've even heard of to get the web browser to interact with the desktop is through a custom ActiveX control -- and even that will only work with Internet Explorer.